# MJPEG Image conversion problem

Tags: ffmpeg

i am facing problem to convert an image to a defined size. i am converting from one image to another image of small size. The command i am executing is:

**C:/xampp/htdocs/jcert6/seyretfiles/tools/converter/ffmpeg.exe -i "c:\knowledge base\videos\user_62\RHSSNet_Image_Library\images\Touchport_II\CD302_14_TPII_17in_PPR_Scanner.jpg" -y -f mjpeg -s 72x92 -vframes 1 -an c:/xampp/htdocs/jcert6/seyretfiles/uploads/thumbnails/user_62/user_62_tmu2qsgo0fr1j5w61292302705_0.jpg**

and i am getting the following error:

*[mjpeg @ 01de0050] unhandled pixel format 0x11111111*

[image2 01cfd080] could not find codec parameters

c:\knowledge base\videos\user_62\RHSSNet_Image_Library\images\Touchport_II\CD302_14_TPII_17in_PPR_Scanner.jpg :could not find codec parameters

please help me :( :(

Comment: why do you want to use ffmpeg to do that??

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use the appropriate software which is
http://www.imagemagick.org/

Edit: Once installed the command is:

```
convert original.jpg -resample 72x92 smaller.jpg
```

Comment: if installing it is not an option at least clean the paths for the executable and images, no one will read that mess.

Comment: Also, since the high-tech equipment you are using relies a lot on image processing, I bet you have it already installed, and probably in the same folder. Basically, your command won't work because it's trying to process a single image as a video. If you are feeling lucky you may paste the next comment and should work.

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/jcert6/seyretfiles/tools/converter/convert.exe "C:\knowledge base\videos\user_62\RHSSNet_Image_Library\images\Touchport_II\CD302_14_TPII_17in_PPR_Scanner.jpg" -resample 72x92 "C:/xampp/htdocs/jcert6/seyretfiles/uploads/thumbnails/user_62/user_62_tmu2qsgo0fr1j5w61292302705_0.jpg"

Comment: thanks for the idea Eric. Actually i was using ffmpeg to extracting all types of media (video, image, etc). this command is not working for very few images. and i am finding a solution for these few images and why these are not extracted.

Comment: You are welcome.  At first glance <i>ffmpeg</i> may look right for this job because it's capable of turning image sequences into video or viceversa.  Keep in mind that video was involved in both.  In conclusion choose ffmpeg if video is involved in any way, for image-to-image conversions it's undesirable (I think is impossible too).  Now let's say you have a folder with a bunch of images to be resized, in that case you want a script to automate the process. If you post a new thread saying you want to resize a whole folder of images, people in this site will kill each other to answer it first.

Comment: Thanks Eric, but i cannot change from ffmpeg to imagemagic as some other business logic attached with that. i checked with other software like imagemagic and it worked. i dont know how i will extract this one?  :(

Comment: Well in that case you need to do something hacky, which may look like a three step solution: 1. Create a little (avi or your fav format) from a single image by repeating it 2. Resample that video.  3. Extract the re-sampled image from the video.  Let me know if a workaround like that may possible in your system.